# Error : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, ef-core-2.0

I'm still learning EF Core and i Hit an error when trying to insert only User Data (Without BusinessUserProfile and BusinessCompany) into database. I have the following tables : User, BusinessUserProfile and BusinessCompany. The relationship is User has one BusinessUserProfile, BusinessCompany has multiple BusinessUserProfile.

My classes are created like this:

User Model Class :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public BusinessUserProfile BusinessUserProfile { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        BusinessUserProfile = new BusinessUserProfile();
    }
}
```

BusinessUserProfile Model Class :

```
public class BusinessUserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public BusinessCompany BusinessCompany { get; set; }
    public int BusinessCompanyId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

}

BusinessCompany Model Class :

```
public class BusinessCompany
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BusinessUserProfile> BusinessUserProfiles { get; set; }

    public BusinessCompany()
    {
        BusinessUserProfiles = new Collection<BusinessUserProfile>();
    }
}
```

DataContext.cs :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(u => u.BusinessUserProfile)
            .WithOne(bup => bup.User)
            .HasForeignKey<BusinessUserProfile>(bup => bup.UserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<BusinessCompany>()
            .HasMany(bc => bc.BusinessUserProfiles)
            .WithOne(bup => bup.BusinessCompany)
            .HasForeignKey(bup => bup.BusinessCompanyId);
```

When i add an User to the database, i got an error : 
MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`businessuserprofiles`, CONSTRAINT `FK_BusinessUserProfiles_BusinessCompanies_BusinessCompanyId` FOREIGN KEY (`BusinessCompanyId`) REFERENCES `businesscompanies` (`id`) ON DELETE C).

Can anyone advise me on this?

Answer (score 0):

This type of error is usually caused when a child table has a foreign key record which is pointing to a parent record which, for some reason, no longer exists.  In your particular case, it usually means there is one or more records in the `BusinessUserProfile` table which is referring to a record in the `BusinessCompany` table which no longer exists.

Here is a query which you may run to flag some orphaned child records:

```
SELECT *
FROM BusinessUserProfile bup
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BusinessCompany bc
                  WHERE bc.id = bup.BusinessCompanyId);
```

If this query turns up records, then it explains your observations.  If not, then at least you can rule out this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You made in `User` class the `BusinessUserProfile` required. So if you try to create a user without an existing `BusinessUserProfile` , its like trying to insert a null fk. Which you did not allow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you point out in which place I set did not allow for null BusinessUserProfile? Is there anyway to set it nullable?

Comment: Just remove BusinessProfile from User class. Or add a property int? BusinessProfileId  in User class. https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship